# cygwin make - undefined referance to INT_MAX and argp_usage

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin

I've not written this program myself nor am I experienced with cygwin and linux but from what I can tell the file seems to have the right include:

```
// tsim_argp.c
#include <argp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>  /* nice */

#include "tsim_argp.h"
```

argp.h which contains argp_usage also got limits.h included which contains INT_MAX so what exactly am I missing? I got all the other c-files compiling just fine it's just this last one that's causing problem.

make dialogue:

```
...
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-pro
totypes -DRESDIR=\"/c/Users/David/Downloads/Train_Simulator/share/tsim\" -g -O2
-MT tsim-tsim_argp.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsim-tsim_argp.Tpo -c -o tsim-tsim_argp.o
 `test -f 'tsim_argp.c' || echo './'`tsim_argp.c
tsim_argp.c: In function 'setpriority':
tsim_argp.c:170:19: error: 'INT_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function)
   if( priority == INT_MAX ) {
                   ^
tsim_argp.c:170:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for e
ach function it appears in
...
Makefile:479: recipe for target 'tsim-tsim_argp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [tsim-tsim_argp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src'
Makefile:247: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84'
Makefile:169: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

make dialogue if I include the limits.h library directly in tsim_argp:

```
...
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src'
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -DRESDIR=\"/c/Users/
David/Downloads/Train_Simulator/share/tsim\" -g -O2 -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lXaw -lXt
-lXmu -lX11 -lXext  -o tsim.exe tsim-AddToggleWidget.o tsim-DialogPopup.o tsim-f
ile.o tsim-resources.o tsim-timer.o tsim-tsim.o tsim-bitmap.o tsim-DrawingPalett
e.o tsim-Graph.o tsim-sound.o tsim-train.o tsim-BitmapDirectory.o tsim-errcheck.
o tsim-pipe.o tsim-Sprite.o tsim-tsim_argp.o  -lXt -lXmu -lXext -lXaw -lX11
tsim-tsim_argp.o: In function `parse_opt':
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:113: undefined refer
ence to `argp_usage'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:113:(.text+0xbe): re
location truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `argp_usage'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:83: undefined refere
nce to `argp_usage'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:83:(.text+0x10e): re
location truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `argp_usage'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:98: undefined refere
nce to `argp_usage'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:98:(.text+0x15c): re
location truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `argp_usage'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:68: undefined refere
nce to `argp_usage'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:68:(.text+0x1a3): re
location truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `argp_usage'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:118: undefined refer
ence to `argp_usage'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:118:(.text+0x294): r
elocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `argp_usage'
tsim-tsim_argp.o:/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:103
: more undefined references to `argp_usage' follow
tsim-tsim_argp.o: In function `parse_opt':
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:103:(.text+0x2c4): r
elocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `argp_usage'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:73:(.text+0x2f4): re
location truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `argp_usage'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:88:(.text+0x324): re
location truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `argp_usage'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:127:(.text+0x354): r
elocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `argp_usage'
tsim-tsim_argp.o: In function `parse':
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:234: undefined refer
ence to `argp_parse'
/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src/tsim_argp.c:234:(.text+0x429): r
elocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `argp_parse'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:228: recipe for target 'tsim.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [tsim.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84/src'
Makefile:247: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/David/Downloads/tsim-0.84'
Makefile:169: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: add `#include <limits.h>`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Tried that and while it removes the INT_MAX errors it still leaves me with the argp_usage errors(Probably should have included the make dialogue for that also) which I don't know how to remove.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/argp_005fusage.html

Comment: Oh, I'm guessing there's no workaround to fix it either?

Answer (score 0):

In Cygwin, it looks like *argp* is separate library. You'll need to add: `-largp` to your *gcc* line.